# Yii captcha validation check does not work

Tags: yii, captcha

This is my model:

```
public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.

        if ($this->scenario == "insert") {
            return array(
                array('requisition_id, sync', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
                array('lastname, firstname, email, dob, phone, cv_path, experienceMonths, experienceYears, competencies, token', 'required', 'message' => "Câmpul este obligatoriu"),
                array('email', 'email', 'message' => "Emailul este invalid!"),
                array('dob', 'validateDob'),
                array('dayOfBirth, monthOfBirth, yearOfBirth', 'safe'),
                array('taleo_id, sync', 'required', 'on' => 'taleoUpdate'),
                array('verifyCode', 'on' => 'insert'),
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            );
        } else if ($this->scenario == 'taleoUpdate') {
            return array(
                array('taleo_id, sync', 'required'),
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            );
        }
        else if($this->scenario == 'notjobapply'){
            return array(
                array('lastname, firstname, email, phone, cv_path, requisition_id', 'required', 'message'=>'Câmpul este obligatoriu'),
                array('email', 'email', 'message' => "Emailul este invalid!"),
            );
        }


        return array(
            array('id, lastname, email, phone, dob, requisition_id, experienceMonths, experienceYears, sync, cv_path, created', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on'=>'captchaRequired'),
        );
    }
```

My problem is that it does not validate the letters from the image. I don't know why. I think that my validation is not correct in the rules. Anyone any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a lot of scenarios and applying different rules to them.

Make sure that the scenario that you're currently running does have a validation rule.

I can see that you use scenarios in two ways, one is the conditions you're using that I'm not fully sure they work, but maybe they do.

And the second is the Yii way, by specifying in the 'on' attribute in every rule declaration.

I would recommend writing all the rules again from scratch in this structure:

```
return array(
    // scenarioA
    array('field1, field2', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioA'),
    array('field1, field2', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioA'),
    array('field1, field2', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioA'),
    // scenarioB
    array('field3, field4', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioB'),
    array('field3, field4', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioB'),
    array('field3, field4', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioB'),
    // scenarioC
    array('field5, field6', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioC'),
    array('field5, field6', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioC'),
    array('field5, field6', 'required', 'on' => 'scenarioC'),
);
```

Or you could keep your condition blocks solution if you test that they behave correctly, but in that case you should remove the 'on' parameter from the rules inside the blocks.

Because for example here:

```
if ($this->scenario == "insert") {
            return array(
                ...
                array('taleo_id, sync', 'required', 'on' => 'taleoUpdate'),
```

You're putting code inside the condition where you verify that scenario is 'insert' but then again you specify the 'on' that will make that rule only be applied on 'taleoUpdate' scenario so it makes no sense.

Oh and as for the captcha, as you can see with your format you only reach the rule for it if the scenario is different from those you've specified above.